# Why does gnome-keyring-daemon not unlock my SSH key?

Tags: ssh-keys, gnome-keyring

I'm running Fedora 24. It used to be that I never had to enter the passphrase for my SSH private key after logging in to GNOME. Now I do.

I still see it listed under `OpenSSH keys` in the `Passwords and Keys` app.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, it turns out the key *must* be writable!

While troubleshooting another issue, I temporarily did `chmod 0` on `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. When I undid that change, I changed it to `400`, thinking nothing should require write access.

Changing it back to `600` and logging out/in fixed my problem.